# What is the maximum number of digits a product has?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have $X \times Y = Z$ where $X,Y \neq 0$ and

- $n$ is the number of digits in $X$
- $m$ is the number of digits in $Y$
- $k$ is the number of digits in $Z$

What is $k$ related to $m$ and $n$?

Thanks

Comment: It suffices to look at the extreme values, which are given respectively by $X, Y$ being both a power of $10$ or both being $1$ less than a power of $10$, e.g. consider $10 \times 100 = 1000$ compared to $9 \times 99 = 891$. You get that the number of digits of $XY$ is at least $m + n - 1$ and at most $m + n$.

Comment: Just check out $\underbrace{999\cdots 9}_n \times \underbrace{999\cdots 9}_m$ and $\underbrace{100 \cdots 0}_n \times \underbrace{100 \cdots 0}_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if $X$ has $n$ digits and $Y$ has $m$ digits, then $X\leq 10^n$ and $Y\leq 10^m$. Therefore $X\cdot Y \leq 10^{m+n}$. It seems that the answer is is $m+n$. It think it is optimal because $3\cdot 4=12$.

Comment: Clear and to the point. Thanks

Comment: Indeed, it is optimal in general: $(3 \times 10^{n - 1}) \times (4 \times 10^{m - 1}) = 1.2 \times 10^{(n+m)-1}$ has $n + m$ digits.

Comment: This is not quite correct. The correct answer is that $XY$ has at most $m+n$ digits, and may have $m + n - 1$ digits. For example $10 \times 10 = 100$.